# Display Term Metabox Only On Certain Term Edit and Add Pages In Admin

Tags: metabox, taxonomy

I have a simple metabox added to a taxonomy and in turn its terms, however I am looking for a way to only display the metabox on a single term of this taxonomy, is this possible?

This metabox with inputs appears on all term edit and term add screens for ALL terms of the taxonomy applied, can this be limited to a single term add and term edit screen?

Regards

John

Comment: I want to add a metabox as well. Could you provide your code for this?